# Having trouble ignoring files in Rsync?

Tags: python, rsync

Alright, I have two folders that need to be in sync, but certain files need to be ignored before the first upload.

To make sense of what I mean lets say for example I have a folder called src and another folder called dest.

src contains settings.properties, some python code, and a template properties file.

dest contains the same settings.properties, same python code but the template properties file is populate during the sync process (done by a script that wraps the protocol)

Now, if I decide to modify the python code in dest, the python code should be updated in src folder, but the new template.properties which is populated should be ignored.

I tried using excludes and includes but I read that you can't use both because "includes takes precedence"

Using Windows, and I am currently using a python script that formats the paths to the default "/cygdrive/C/" then I populate the properties file, then I run rsync

Comment: Maybe try to reorganize your includes/excludes... Try reading up here: http://www.hyperorg.com/blogger/2008/05/10/beginner-to-beginner-rsync-exclude-from/

Comment: Note that the command `cygpath` "converts Windows native filenames to Cygwin POSIX-style pathnames and vice versa" you might be able to do without that python script.

Comment: But I don't have Cgywin installed?